# How to flag/close because a question belongs someplace else

Tags: support

I wanted to either vote to close or flag https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11360/form-get-method-prints-viewstate-value-in-addressbar as suitable for SO.SE, but I could only suggest it belongs on ac.meta.se (which it doesn't). If something belongs on another SE site how do I vote to close for that reason?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite counter-intuitive, but here is how it should be done:

[image: image with hand-drawn circle]

As you noted, the “belongs on another SE site” only lists a few pre-determined sites (which we can ask the moderators to complement if we wish). Everything else is “other”.

Comment: As a mod, I'd rather you not take this approach; for us mods, the third option—"this questin belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"—contains a text box which we can use to send the question to any site on the SE network. Flag it and we'll take care of it.

Comment: @eykanal okay… it's a bit sad that this has to go through flagging, while the whole infrastructure for closing is otherwise quite streamlined

Comment: I hear ya, and I definitely agree. [I posted this request to Meta a long time ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110996/139256), but The Powers That Be feel that it would enable too many frivolous migrations. \**shrug*\* Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Mods have the option to send it to any other site. Flag it and we'll send it there.

Comment: Presumably you mean flag it as " it needs ♦ moderator attention" since if I flag it as "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" I just get to the same place as if I am trying to close it.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably right. I don't use the flagging system that much, as I'm more often on the other end of it :)